# Is it possible to define a callback function for Facebook follow button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have implemented the facebook follow button using the Javascript SDK method as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button).

Has anyone been able to successfully define a callback function that would trigger when a user clicks on the FB follow button?

I have checked the event subscription method mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.9) but it doesnot say anything about the follow button.

Comment: if it´s not in the even list, then there is most likely no event for it. what would you need it for anyway?

Comment: I need this for tracking follow/unfollow events... its a business requirement

Comment: i do not think that there is a possibility for this. follow/unfollow is for private user profiles anyway, there is no business involved and there are no insights either.